# Assigning the same column/rownames names to many matrices in For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, names

I have a whole bunch of matrices that I want to assign column and row names to based on a column of names that are held in another column (Names) in a dataframe (months) I have.

Each matrix I want to assign names to corresponds to a  concatenated "partner" string and metric held here e.g. one of the matrices is called "facebook_Total_Completed_Rentals":

```
Metrics = c('_Total_Completed_Rentals','_Registered_Completed_rentals',
'_Registered_renters','_New_Registrations')

Partners = c('facebook', 'altrooz', 'adperio', 'snapchat', 'apple', 'google')
```

I want to loop through these two to assign the names to the matrices in this way to avoid having to manually code out all the colnames and row.names statements:

```
for(i in 1:length(Metrics)){
  for(j in 1:length(Partners)){
  temp = paste0(Partners[j],Metrics[i])
  colnames(temp)= months$Names[1:(months_cut-1)]
  row.names(temp) = months$Names[1:(months_cut-1)]
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = months$Names[1:(months_cut - 1)]) : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Please help

Comment: Fundamentally you need to use `get` to return environment object by name. Try `tmp_matrix <- get(temp)` inside loop as *temp* is a character value and not actual matrix object. But ideally, you save all similar structured matrices in a list and not as separate objects and call it by list and its name: `list$facebook_Total_Completed_Rentals`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following data.frames :

```
iris_a  <- iris[1:2,]
iris_b  <- iris[3:4,]
iris_c  <- iris[5:6,]
```

The clean way to do what you want is to put them in a list and apply changes on it :

```
rnms <- c("foo","bar")
your_list <- lapply(list(iris_a = iris_a,iris_b = iris_b, iris_c = iris_c), function(x){
  rownames(x) <- rnms
  x
})
```

Then if necessary you can extract its elements back to your local environment :

```
list2env(your_list, environment())
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# foo          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# bar          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

A bit more compact using `tidyverse` :

```
your_list <- map(lst(iris_a, iris_b, iris_c), `rownames<-`, rnms)
```

Comment: what if the matrices were in different sizes?

Comment: Then you can't give them the same dimension names.

Comment: A bit more compact using `base`: `your_list <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern="iris_")), "row.names<-", rnms)`

Comment: @Parfait but OP doesn't have a pattern in his real data :)

Comment: Instead of `ls()` you could put something like `apply(expand.grid(Partners, Metrics), 1, paste, collapse = "")`

Comment: Or use `outer`: `all_matrices <- as.vector(outer(Partners, Metrics, paste0))` and pass in *all_matrices* into `mget`.

Comment: I read the question a bit fast, I see that I don't answer everything. As far as I can see the structure of the data suggests that OP should have a list of list, or maybe even a single data frame with appropriate additional columns. So my advice would be to sort things out upstream rather than hacking them at this point.

Answer (score 0):

While @Moody's answer is probably the cleaner option, I thought I'd provide code that does what you originally wanted it to do:

Let's create 4 matrices whose names are combinations of 2 elements:

```
a_1 <- a_2 <- b_1 <- b_2 <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 5)
```

Vector of row names and column names:

```
rnames <- paste0("row_", 1:4)
cnames <- paste0("col_", 1:5)
```

Get the name elements:

```
x <- c("a", "b")
y <- 1:2
```

For your loop, you need to realise that `temp` is just a character string so `colnames(temp)` will not work. You want to create a string that includes the entire command, parse it as an expression, and then evaluate it:

```
for (i in x) {
  for (j in y) {
    temp <- paste(i, j, sep = "_")
    eval(parse(text = paste0("dimnames(", temp, ") <- list(rnames, cnames)")))
  }
}
```

Note.  `dimnames(temp)` is quicker than `rownames` and `colnames`.